# Keep adding one to filename until file not found

Tags: php

I am writing an upload script, and I want to check to see if the filename is already taken. If it is, add `_1` to the filename. If that's taken, keep adding +1 digit until the filename is available. (_2, _3, _4, etc)

```
$targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku'].'.'.$ext;
if (file_exists($targetFile)) {
    $targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku'].'_1.'.$ext; // Automate this...
}

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

How can I loop through incrementing numbers to find a file that's not taken?

Comment: Probably better to just [glob](http://www.php.net/glob) the files by pattern and loop over the resulting array looking for a hole (or sort and get the last value then increment that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku'].'.'.$ext;
$temp=1;
while (file_exists($targetFile)) {
    $targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku']."_{$temp}.".$ext;
    $temp++;
}
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use while loop to determine until the file exists and increment the variable extended to it.

```
$targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku'].'.'.$ext;
$i=1;
while (file_exists($targetFile)) {
    $targetFile = $targetPath.$_POST['sku']."_{$i}.".$ext;
    $i++;
}
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

Comment: you don't need to comment that this is an answer. it's obviously in the "Answer" section...